# magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: magento2, javascript, product-images, media-images, gallery-image

Magento 2.3.5 getting error on the product detail page of configurable product -

Getting this error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Object.returnCurrentImages (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:508:46)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._onGalleryLoaded (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:706:62)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.eval [as _onGalleryLoaded] (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:102:41)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:5234:27)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:4886:29)
    at Object.trigger (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:5138:13)
    at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:635:22)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:5868:18)
    at Function.each (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:378:20)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (eval at require.load (VM605 static.js:340), <anonymous>:144:18)
```

Why we are getting this error and how can we solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the element `[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]` does not exist on the page, therefore `element` is undefined here:

```
var galleryObject = element.data('gallery');
```

Which is on line 731 in `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` on the version of Magento I am using.

I can't be 100% sure on that but it's what it looks like based on your error.

Comment: on page 2 div is exist on this div 1 - <div class="gallery-placeholder" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
2 - <div class="fotorama-item" data-gallery-role="gallery">

Comment: Does it exist at the point that JS runs? If you add a breakpoint or console.log(element) above that line?